# What does number mean next to artist name in on-line music databases?

Tags: windows, mp3, database, music, tags

I am using *MusicBrainz*, *Discogs* and *freedb* through *Mp3tag* application for Windows for clearing up my .mp3 files library using these on-line databases as tags sources. Sometimes (approx. 3-5% of all searches) I am getting an number in parenthesis next to artist name, i.e.:

[image]

What does this denote?

Comment: Avid Mp3Tag user since can't even remember when, never seen that. My best guesses: duplicate files, or duplicate sources for the same exact tag info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dave Power (5)" means that's the 5th distinct artist named Dave Power in the Discogs database.

(I found out by entering "Dave Power" into Discogs search and seeing multiple results numbered in that way, describing different musicians from different locations.)

For example:

- https://www.discogs.com/artist/1820-Straight-No-Chaser
- https://www.discogs.com/artist/2386721-Straight-No-Chaser-3
- https://www.discogs.com/artist/370980-Dave-Power
- https://www.discogs.com/artist/3162890-Dave-Power-5
- https://www.discogs.com/artist/4504746-Dave-Power-6